# Code in all modules in personal.xlsb is not visible and will not run

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very unusual situation which I’ve never heard of before that involves my PERSONAL.XLSB file. It also involves new macros recorded in a working spreadsheet that is not macro enabled. I am running a fully updated Win10 Pro and am using Office 365 Personal Edition with the documents stored locally on my C: drive.

The major impact is that I can’t see any code within PERSONAL.XLSB even though I can see the modules themselves in the navigation pane. Several of those macros are on my QAT, and they do work when the QAT icon is clicked, but I can’t view the code for any module. If I attempt to add one of the other macros to my QAT none of the PERSONAL.XLSB macros are listed as available to be added.

When I right click a module in the VB Editor for PERSONAL.XLSB and select to export the module, the dialog box and process appears to do its job, but the code is not exported. If I export a module in one of my working xlsm files the export works as it should.

If I attempt to record a macro in a new file (unsaved) to be stored in “This Workbook”, accepting the default macro name of Macro1, I get an error message that says the syntax of the name isn’t correct! That also happens if I try to record a macro in a working xlsx file. I can record a macro or create one directly in the VB Editor for an xlsm file.

I can’t remove or add a module, although onscreen the processes seem to run without any errors.

Additional troubleshooting efforts I made are as follows.
I physically disconnected both backup drives then:

1. Performed a cold boot.
2. Moved PERSONAL.XLSB out of c:...\XLSTART into a subdirectory under my documents folder and renamed it to a variation of the name, but still as .xlsb.
3. Confirmed with a search of the entire C: drive that there was no file anywhere on the drive with the name PERSONAL.XLSB, only the renamed version of it in the C:\Users...\Documents\Macros folder.
4. Performed a cold boot.
   When I then launched Excel, even though book.xltx and sheet.xltx were still in the XLSTART folder there was no Book1 showing when Excel started. I opened a new blank worksheet from the File menu and then used ALT-F11 to open the VB Editor. The VB project with the **renamed** xlsb still showed in the editor navigation pane but was still unusable. Somehow it is still linked to Excel.

Is there any way to either get PERSONAL.XLSB working again, or possibly extract the code from the file and rebuild a new PERSONAL.XLSB? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I got the problem fixed by copying the old PERSONAL.XLSB to my desktop and renaming it. I then started Excel and used file explorer to open and repair the renamed file , saving it to my desktop. I exited Excel, then moved the corrupted/broken file out of XLSTART and copied the repaired file into that directory. Renamed it back to PERSONAL.XLSB. Launched Excel and the repaired PERSONAL.XLSG works just fine. I can see, edit, and add macros as needed. Thanks to Microsoft Support for pointing me to the repair process.